# Including pictures when forwarding a company website

Tags: facebook-sharer, graphical-logo

I want to change the picture that appears when you post a link to my website to replace it with my logo.

I understand that I can control the exact title, description, and thumbnail that Facebook  uses by adding specific meta tags to your "index.html" and have read the Facebook developers' support page. Although I added the code

```
<meta property="og:title" content="title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="thumbnail_image" />
```

and updated "title", "description" and "thumbnail_image" with my preferred entries, this made no difference as Facebook still used (by default) the other images that are on the index.html. The link allows you to choose from these images when you post the link but it does not offer my logo that I placed under content in "thumbnail_image".

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does some caching on the URLs it displays.  Try using [this tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to debug the problem.  It will also refresh whatever information is cached about your website.